# Verificar con isdigit en c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un programa donde quiero pedirle nombres al usuario, cada nombre estará acompañado de un código de usuario de 5 dígitos y los datos serán guardados dentro de un arreglo de 10x2.
El código debe de ser ingresado de manera manual y no son aceptadas letras o símbolos.

Quiero que cuando el usuario teclee letras o símbolos aparezca un mensaje de error y me permita intentarlo otra vez sin salir de la consola ya sea que el usuario se equivoque una vez o varias, imprime el mensaje de error pero no me deja ingresar los datos de nuevo y se cierra la consola (primera imagen), cuando si me deja ingresar datos de nuevo ya no lo revisa para ver si esta bien escrito y se cierra (segunda foto), me podrían decir que estoy haciendo mal?

Otro problema que tengo y que no logro resolver es que al parecer "isdigit" solo revisa el primer espacio, si pongo por ejemplo "98p75" me lo marca como correcto, hay alguna manera de que revise espacio por espacio para ver si es un numero o carácter?

Esta solo es una parte del código para ver si funciona, aun me falta lo de ingresar nombres y un menú para mostrar o ingresar datos.
Perdonen si son muchas dudas pero apenas voy ingresando al mundo de la programación con c++ y si me surgen dudas de repente :'.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    char dato[10][2];
    int fil = 10, col = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i <= fil; i++) 
    {
        cout << "\nCodigo de usuario (5 numeros): "; cin >> dato[i][0];
        
        if (!isdigit(dato[i][0]))
        {
            do
            {   
                cout << "ADVERTENCIA: el codigo contiene letras o simbolos, por favor solo ingresa numeros";
                cout << "\nCodigo de usuario (5 numeros): "; cin >> dato[i][0];
            } while (isdigit(dato[i][0]) != 0);
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal es que la función [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) se limita a comparar si el caracter introducido es numérico. Así que para saber si la cadena completa cumple, has de comparar cada caracter que la forma. Lo más sencillo podría ser crearte una función que, haciendo caso de `isdigit`, recorra cada caracter y si en algún momento se encuentra uno que no es numérico, devuelva `false`, y si llega hasta el final (caracter `'\0'`) devuelva `true`

Algo como:

```
bool validar (const char* texto)
{
    int i=0;
    while (texto[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (!isdigit(texto[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Otro problema es cómo tienes definido el array. Un array [10][2] está diciendo que tienes 10 array de dos caracteres cada uno. Tal vez sería mejor definir 2 arrays de 5 caracteres cada uno. Si quieres mantener los 10, sin problemas, pero realmente con un tamaño de 6 (5 por el tamaño del código + 1 para la cadena de terminación `'\0'` sería suficiente.

Puedes definirlo todo con unas constantes al comienzo:

```
const int num_codigos = 2;
const int ancho_codigos = 10;  //aquí puedes poner 6
```

Y ya, juntándolo todo, este podría ser tu código adaptado:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>

using namespace std;

const int num_codigos = 2;
const int ancho_codigos = 10;  //aquí puedes poner 6

bool validar (const char* texto);


int main()
{
    char datos[num_codigos][ancho_codigos];
    for (int i = 0; i < num_codigos; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nCodigo de usuario (5 numeros): ";
        cin >> datos[i];
        if (!validar(datos[i]))
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "ADVERTENCIA: el codigo contiene letras o simbolos, por favor solo ingresa numeros";
                cout << "\nCodigo de usuario (5 numeros): "; cin >> datos[i];
            } while (!validar(datos[i]));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool validar (const char* texto)
{
    int i=0;
    while (texto[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (!isdigit(texto[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No hay necesidad alguna de usar `isdigit`. Se pueden usar números directamente y jugar con los mismos para validar los datos.

Al usar números no podemos usar `strlen` o `std::string.length()` para saber la longitud de la cadena. Sin embargo si podremos usar logaritmos en base 10.

Es facil verificar lo siguiente:

```
log10(1)     = 0
log10(10)    = 1
log10(100)   = 2
log10(1000)  = 3
log10(10000) = 4
```

Para saber cuántos dígitos tiene un número basta con calcular la componente entera de log10 del número y, a esa cantidad, sumarle 1.

Dicho esto, vamos con las posibles soluciones:

**Usar `std::cin` directamente**

```
int valor;
std::cin >> valor;
if( std::cin.bad() || std::log10(valor) != 4)
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//                    Comprueba el número de dígitos del entero log10(1)=0, log10(100) = 2
//  Comprueba si el primer caracter de entrada es 
{
    // No se ha introducido un número o la secuencia numérica no es de 5 dígitos
    std::cin.clear(); // limpiamos bit de error
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n'); // Descartamos el contenido de stdin

    std::cout << "Código no válido";
}
```

La desventaja de este sistema es que no podrías detectar entradas tipo `"12345abcd"`. Mientras la parte numérica tenga 5 dígitos, el sistema lo validará como bueno (pero solo se quedará con los 5 dígitos).

**Usar un buffer intermedio**

```
std::string buffer;
std::cin >> buffer;

if(buffer.length() == 5))
{
    std::stringstream ss(buffer);
  
    int valor;
    ss >> valor;

    if( ss.bad() || std::log10(valor) != 4 )
    {
        // No se ha introducido un número o la secuencia numérica no es de 5 dígitos
        std::cout << "Código no válido";
    }
}
else
{
    // Secuencia con una longitud diferente a 5 dígitos
    std::cout << "Código no válido";
}
```

Esta solución es un poco más rebuscada pero, a cambio te detectará como incorrectas las secuencias que el primer sistema no sería capaz de identificar.

Comment: Madre mía. Esto sí que es programación avanzada :-)

Comment: @user3733164 gracias, pero tampoco es para tanto, solo son soluciones alternativas a la tuya ;)

Comment: @user3733164 luego dicen que las matemáticas no son importantes. No les creas. Sí lo son.